# Insufficient system memory in resource pool to execute SQL Scripts in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a tool which has been developed in C#.Net 2005 and it will create Database by executing SQL scripts; the scripts are running in batch.

When run in XP it works fine; but problem starts when it runs in Windows Vista 32 bit O.S. with SQR Server 2008 Express; I am logging the error in log file; below are the log with Size of the script files.

I don't understand why there less memory available to excute the scripts, earlier I faced this and broke the Master_Meata_Data into two files (Master_Data_Metadata1 and Master_Data_Metadata2); still I am facing the same issue in Vista.

> 08/28/2009  In DB progress start: Local\SQLEXPRESS:WINDOWS::1031:NEWDB
>   bgWorkerCreateDB_DoWork:C:\Program Files\CreateNewDB\
>
> ReadAndExecuteScript: C:\Program Files\CreateNewDB\Drop_Create.sql
>   (Size 3KB)
>
> ReadAndExecuteScript: C:\Program Files\CreateNewDB\Tables.sql (Size
>   999KB )
>
> ReadAndExecuteScript: C:\Program Files\CreateNewDB\Master_Data.sql
>   (Sizr 649KB)
>
> ReadAndExecuteScript: C:\Program
>   Files\CreateNewDB\Master_Data_Metadata1.sql (Size 2.72MB)
>   ***Friday, August 28, 2009  SQL Error in ReadAndExecuteScript: There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'internal' to run this
>   query.***
>
> Friday, August 28, 2009  5:10 PM ReadAndExecuteScript: C:\Program
>   Files\CreateNewDB\Data_Metadata2.sql (Size 1.55MB )
>   ***Friday, August 28, 2009  SQL Error in ReadAndExecuteScript: There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'internal' to run this
>   query.***
>
> ReadAndExecuteScript: C:\Program Files\CreateNewDB\Initialize_Data.sql
>   (Size 14.3MB)
>
> ReadAndExecuteScript: C:\Program Files\CreateNewDB\Views1.sql (Size
>   2KB)
>
> ReadAndExecuteScript: C:\Program Files\CreateNewDB\Views2.sql (Size
>   4KB)
>
> ReadAndExecuteScript: C:\Program Files\CreateNewDB\Views3.sql (Size
>   2KB)
>
> ReadAndExecuteScript: C:\Program Files\CreateNewDB\Fn_Duration.sql
>   (Size 2.27KB)
>
> ReadAndExecuteScript: C:\Program Files\CreateNewDB_Fn_GetDate.sql
>   (Size 1KB)

Answer (score 2):

I can't answer the question of why it works in XP and not Vista, but when you see that error message associated with a very large script, it usually means that the query batch is too big for the *parser* to handle.

Are there any `GO` statements in those scripts?  If not, that's probably what's causing the failure.  More than 1 MB is pretty big for a SQL script that hasn't been split into batches.  Either put some `GO` statements in there or (better yet) split it up into smaller scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are just running out of physical memory, but if I you aren't and have the resource governor enabled try using

```
ALTER RESOURCE GOVERNOR 
    { DISABLE | RECONFIGURE }
|
        WITH ( CLASSIFIER_FUNCTION = { schema_name.function_name | NULL } )
|
    RESET STATISTICS
[ ; ]
```

and

```
ALTER WORKLOAD GROUP { group_name | "default" }
[ WITH
    ([ IMPORTANCE = { LOW | MEDIUM | HIGH } ]
           [ [ , ] REQUEST_MAX_MEMORY_GRANT_PERCENT = value ]
           [ [ , ] REQUEST_MAX_CPU_TIME_SEC = value ]
           [ [ , ] REQUEST_MEMORY_GRANT_TIMEOUT_SEC = value ]
           [ [ , ] MAX_DOP = value ]
           [ [ , ] GROUP_MAX_REQUESTS = value ] )
 ]
[ USING { pool_name | "default" } ]
[ ; ]
```

to alter the amount of memory available for executing queries.

[MSDN Page for ALTER RESOURCE GOVERNOR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934013.aspx)

[MSDN page for ALTER WORKLOAD GROUP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895361.aspx)