# "Insufficient System Memory" Error in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I get the following error in SQL Server 2008:

`There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'internal' to run this query.`

I recently migrated from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2008, and the system is Windows Server 2K8.

Comment: service pack version, 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: can you post the DBCC MEMORYSTATUS dump information from your error log.

Comment: Also, how much memory on the machine, if 32-bit have you enabled /3GB and/or /PAE, how much memory have you allocated to SQL Server, and have you configured the resource governor in any way?

Comment: we have 4 GB total memory and we enabled 2.5 gb for SQL server .We disabled Resource governer

Comment: perhaps have a look at some of the answers

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 connect bugs reported: [One](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/342696/there-is-insufficient-system-memory-in-resource-pool-internal-to-run-this-query) ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20130717090940/https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/342696/there-is-insufficient-system-memory-in-resource-pool-internal-to-run-this-query)) and [Two](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/484787/there-is-insufficient-system-memory-in-resource-pool-internal-to-run-this-query) ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20130719055331/http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/484787/there-is-insufficient-system-memory-in-resource-pool-internal-to-run-this-query))

At least two SO questions: [One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537812/there-is-insufficient-system-memory-in-resource-pool-internal) and [Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404128/insufficient-system-memory-in-resource-pool-to-execute-sql-scripts-in-sql-server)

These may offer something

Answer (score 0):

Try using the -g switch as described in this [MS KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316749) to increase the amount of virtual memory reserved for sql server.

Answer (score 0):

The are a -G parameter at sqlserver comfiguration to increse the memtoleave portion memory, reponsable area to execute queries, backups, openqueries, etc. By default, the inital value is 256mb. I suggest increase by 128Mb, but take care about that value.  Try to serialize simultaneous executions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a serious look at your queries.  This could happen if you're doing and 'IN'/'NOT IN' compare on a large string value passed into a query.  Rather do it on a lookup table/temp table